# jquery if any of the class value equals

Tags: jquery

Basically, I want to check if any of the element with a class value is either free or paid. 5 select elements, if any of them has select free or paid.

Something like:

```
if ($(".listing_ticket_type").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }) == 'free') {
        $('.ticketing-bank').hide();
} else {
        $('.ticketing-bank').show();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your "*[mcve]*" code (including your relevant HTML and CSS as well as the jQuery/JavaScript); that way your question is - probably of more use to future users of the site - and less likely to be closed as 'off-topic' (because questions about "why doesn't this code work?" must be accompanied by the relevant code to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is slightly off - you need to filter and check the length of items returned is greater than 0. There is a shortcut for this. A length of `0` is falsey. So anything greater will be truthy.

```
if ($(".listing_ticket_type").filter(function() { 
        var val = $(this).val();
        return val == "free" || val == "paid"; 
    }).length) {
        $('.ticketing-bank').hide();
} else {
        $('.ticketing-bank').show();
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this code is that it has to go through each element.

Comment: @31piy Sure - but with just 5 elements thats not such a problem.  (From Question: `5 select elements`)

Comment: @Jamiec yes the total is 5. BTW how can I check if paid exist in the array because now, if there is paid in any of the select, it still hides the ticketing-bank

Comment: @Shina - see update. I missed that you wanted to check for `free` or `paid`